# Get lower bits of a double in C#

Tags: c#, bit

I got a number in a double variable.

How can I take only the 4 lower bits of the number and save them somewhere else?

Comment: Floating point numbers have bits now? Do you mean digits?

Comment: @leppie why wouldn't they have bits?

Comment: @harold: bits is only a size indication. They consist of a sign, mantissa and exponent. By themselves, the bits used in storage is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @leppie they have a well-defined meaning (there's no choice of floating point format in C#, it's IEEE 754 binary64), so that's something. I don't immediately see how the lowest 4 bits will be useful to OP though.

Comment: @harold, so what is the value (or meaning) of the last 4 bits of the mantissa or exponent? Nothing! They only have meaning when used together. You are in fact referring to storage.

Comment: @leppie that sounds rather philosophical. I'm not trying to suggest that the value 0.5 fundamentally has "4 last bits that are zero", but in C# a `double` with the value 0.5 certainly does.

Comment: I actually wrote double by mistake.. it was supposed to be long :)

Comment: @YonatanNir well that's .. disappointing. Just `value & 0xF` then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `BitConverter.GetBytes` to get all 8 bytes in a byte array. Do what you wish with them from there.

If you really meant the lowest four *bits*, then you want:

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(someDouble);
int low4bits = bytes[0] & 0xf;
```

If it is actually four *bytes* that you are looking for, then you follow the call to `BitConverter.GetBytes()` by a call to `Array.Copy()`.

Answer (score 2):

By converting it (bit-by-bit) to a `long` first, so you can apply bitwise operators:

```
long bits = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(your_double);
int lowest_4_bits = (int)bits & 0xF;
```